# matplotlib vertical space in the background

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've plated a bar graph where I set a default horizontal span:

```
plt.axhspan(0,2, color='yellow', alpha=0.25)
```

[image]

However it looks like that yellow area covers my original bars. How can I make a horizontal span to be in a background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zorder and set zorder of the histogram higher than zorder of the hspan:

```
plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, zorder=1)
plt.axhspan(0, 0.01, facecolor='yellow', zorder=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zorder` when plotting your graph.

For example with a scatter plot;

```
plt.axhspan(0, 2, color='yellow', alpha=0.25)
plt.scatter(X, Y, zorder=10)
```

This ensures your graph is on top of the `axhspan`.

`zorder` can be defined for many plt functions, just check the api, this is useful if you have many overlaying subplots for example.